# This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type float option

Tags: ocaml

Hi i need to prepare for an exam and our teacher gave us some work to do here is my question i have an error i can't solve. We are working on arithmetic expression here is my type :

```
type expr_a = Val of float
|Var of string
|Plus of expr_a * expr_a
|Moins of expr_a * expr_a
|Div of expr_a * expr_a
|Mult of expr_a * expr_a
|Umoins of expr_a
|Puiss of float * float
|Sin of expr_a
|Cos of expr_a
|Exp of expr_a
|Ln of expr_a ;;
```

i already did a function that display the arithmetic expression which is working but now he gave us a function that we need to use

```
let valeuropt v =
if v = "x" then Some(0.)
else if v = "y" then Some(1.)
else None;;
```

when i try to use this i get an error: "This expression has type float but an expression was expected of type"
         float option

```
let rec partielle expr = match expr with
Var x -> valeuropt x
|Val x -> x
|Plus (e1,e2) -> (evaluer e1 +. evaluer e2)
|Moins (e1,e2) -> (evaluer e1 -. evaluer e2)
|Div (e1,e2) -> (evaluer e1 /. evaluer e2)
|Mult (e1,e2) -> (evaluer e1 *. evaluer e2)
|Puiss(a,b) -> a**b
|Sin(e) -> sin(evaluer e)
|Cos(e) -> cos(evaluer e)
|Exp(e) -> exp(evaluer e)
|Ln(e) -> log(evaluer e)
|Umoins(e) -> -. evaluer e;;
```

Comment: Is it normal that `partielle` calls `evaluer`? Shouldn't it call `partielle`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see, `valeuropt` returns a value of type `float option` which basically mean "maybe a value containing a float, maybe a value containing nothing".

However, in your code, you treat it as if it would return a `float` which is incompatible with `float option`.

I guess your teacher wants you to provide a `partielle` function that would return a `float option` (depending on its usage of forbidden variables).

The later function (and others that look like it) may be of some help in that task:

```
let map_opt f x =
 match x with
 | None -> None
 | Some y -> Some (f y)
```